# Can I use numbers in descriptions to force a loading order for SQL files?

Tags: flyway

Playing around with Flyway and I have one question, for the Initial Version (for a completely new blank database), can I modularise the SQL files to be something like:

```
V0_1_0__01Initial_Version.sql
V0_1_0__02Setup_Countries.sql
V0_1_0__03Create_Default_Organisation.sql
```

and so on, so that I force a precise loading order of the SQL files?

Nothing in the documentation suggests I *can't* do this, but then again, nothing in the documentation suggests I *can* do this :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently not!

Here's an example with the above format:

    Exception in thread "main" com.googlecode.flyway.core.validation.ValidationException: Found more than one migration with version '0.1.0' (Offenders: SQL '/home/fubar/workspaces/java/fubar/fubar-db/tmp/build/db/migration/_0/_1/_0/V0_1_0__000Initial_Version.sql' and SQL '/home/fubar/workspaces/java/fubar/fubar-db/tmp/build/db/migration/_0/_1/_0/V0_1_0__010Import_Countries.sql')
     [java]  at com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.CompositeMigrationResolver.checkForIncompatibilities(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:192)

:-(

Answer (score 1):

No, the ordering is achieved through the version number. You have to move your ordering number into the version number itself.

Answer (score 0):

What Alex is alluding to and what works wonderfully, is simply to do this:

```
V0_1_0_001__Initial_Version.sql
V0_1_0_002__Setup_Countries.sql
V0_1_0_003__Create_Default_Organisation.sql
```

As you can see, the 001, 002 and 003 are now part of the version — a bit like a very minor patch level.